# What are some quick ways to setup Product Displays in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

What is a fast way to create product displays in drupal commerce? Say I created 50 different unique products and now they are all over the place on the product list, how can I intuitively add these 50 products to a product display?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/commerce_auto_product_display

Comment: "Fast way" is rather subjective; it is like asking for the best way of doing something. Furthermore, since nobody is probably going to measure which is effectively the faster way, there would not be any objective parameter to judge the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding product manually then you can use [Auto Product Display](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_auto_product_display) module to set display of the product at the same time when you create product. But if you are using [commerce feed](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) along with [feed](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) then you will have to set two separate importer for each of them.